# What is the common practice to choose between <iframe> and <php include>?

Tags: php, html, iframe, include

I'm working on the index.(php/html) page and need to add some files from other folders. I'm able to keep those files as php or html. Is there any general rule of when and under which circumstances it would be better to use `<iframe>` rather than `<?php include>` to add such files?

HTLM
`<iframe src="example.html" width="1280" height="300">`

PHP   `<?php include 'example.php'; ?>`

Comment: Although these are not comparable, in short, don't do iframe, use php include.

Comment: no need to use iframe for internal website, iframe mostly used for loading external domain.

Comment: I suggest you read up on the difference. They really can not be compared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An iframe basically turns a region of your webpage into a completely separate webpage: a full-blown http request will be performed to fill in the iframe, and the resulting contents will be its own distinct webpage, with its own DOM, its own CSS rules, etc.. Literally a completely different wepbage that happens to be stuck inside a square region of another.

PHP's include will load up and spit out some html that becomes PART of the surrounding html. It will be part of the main DOM, it will be subject to the main page's CSS rules... because it won't be a seperate page, it'll just be a chunk of a greater whole.

Both have their good points/bad points, and we can't recommend either one, because their usage is dictated by your needs.

Answer (score 4):

They are done completely differently.

**SHORT ANSWER**

Use `<?php include 'example.php'; ?>`

**LONG ANSWER**

The PHP file actually takes the code at a server level and inserts it and executes any code that is within that file. All the PHP code is completed and then the whole page is served back to the client as one piece

An iframe should almost solely be used to insert another website's content into your own. It requires another HTTP request to wherever you are linking it to, and loads it into it's own special box with it's own properties.

*I would never use an iframe as an include.*

An example of where it is useful. Let's say you are selling furniture on your website, and you want to put a room builder (where you can select the layout of furniture and color and so on). You found a website with an excellent room builder, and so one your site, one of your pages you simply iframe that other content, so you now have a room builder on your website (and the other website isn't seen to the common observer).

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what your needs are since they do totally different things.  I'd also like to point out that `include` will work on `.html` files too as well as text files or pretty much anything else.

If you just want to include additional HTML content from another file on the same page, use `include`.

`<iframe>` creates a new browsing context and can have undesirable effects.  For example, if you navigate to a URL in the iframe, the parent document remains at the same URL.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should "never" include an iframe pointing to your own site on your site.

So, if you want to include stuff in your page, use `include`.

Answer (score 0):

The iframe leaves the retrieval of the contents to the client. An iframe can be used to include content from any location.
The php option occurs on the server and I believe can only include local content.
It depends on what you are out to achieve.

edit: after more research,
 `allow_url_include` in php.ini controls whether you are able to include remote content. 
This will obviously cause the server to retrieve that content and so will incur associated costs.